# Is there a way to automatically generate class diagrams for Flutter projects other than the dcdg package?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I wanted to automatically generate class diagrams for my Flutter project, so I tried using the [dcdg](https://pub.dev/packages/dcdg) package. However, I learned that it doesn't work when packages that use annotations like freezed or hive are included as dependencies. Therefore, if there are any packages or plugins other than the dcdg package that can generate class diagrams or sequence diagrams for Flutter projects, I would appreciate it if you could let me know.